# css columns get top element on every column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For example, I have an html page where it contains paragraphs. Just like this for example:

```
<html>
<head><title>Paragraphs</title></head>
<body>
<p> Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren</p> <br/>
<p> Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren</p> <br/>
<p> Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren</p> <br/>
<p> Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren</p> <br/>
<p> Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren Lorem Lorem Lorem Loren</p> <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display it in columns so I used columns-width, columns-gap. The question is, how would I know the element on the top most of each column. I've managed to get the element for a particular column. I want to know what would be the element of the next column/s.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yQxC2/11/
My Question is how would I know the top most element on the 1st column, 2nd column and so on. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: can't understand your question.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking here. Maybe it's because there's no question. Or because you didn't really explain it in a proper way. Please edit the question.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate your code & problem

Comment: I belive he is using [css3 columns](http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your tags I see you use jQuery.

Use each:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").each(function() {
        alert(this.childNodes[0]); 
    });
});
```